# "Compile Error: Method or Data Member Not Found" when the sub is right there in the same module

Tags: excel, vba, compiler-errors

Just need some fresh eyes on this:

```
'@Folder "COM"
Option Explicit

Private defaultQIfunction As LongPtr
Private compositionInterface As IUnknown

'works with thisPtr to Object or Concrete
Private Function SimpleWoof(ByRef thisPtr As LongPtr) As Long
    Debug.Print "Simple woof "; thisPtr
    SimpleWoof = 0
End Function

'Fine
'c Object, ByVal this IUnk
'c Class1, ByVal this IUnk
'c Object/Class1, ByVal this Object
'ByVal As Concrete

'Fail
'c Class1, ByRef this IUnk
'c Object, ByRef this IUnk

Private Function ObjWoof(ByRef thisObj As Class1) As Long
    Debug.Print "Obj woof "; TypeName(thisObj)
End Function

Public Function InvokeQueryInterface(ByVal this As LongPtr, ByVal riid As LongPtr, ByVal ppvObject As LongPtr, Optional ByVal funcPtr As LongPtr = 0) As Long
    Static caller As New cUniversalDLLCalls
    If funcPtr = 0 Then
        InvokeQueryInterface = caller.CallFunction_COM(this, 0, CR_HRESULT, CC_STDCALL, riid, ppvObject)
    Else
        InvokeQueryInterface = caller.CallFunction_RAW(funcPtr, CR_HRESULT, CC_STDCALL, this, riid, ppvObject)
    End If
End Function

Private Function IUnknown_QueryInterface(ByVal this As IUnknown, _
                                         ByVal riid As LongPtr, _
                                         ByVal ppvObject As LongPtr _
                                         ) As Long
    If defaultQIfunction <= 0 Then
        Debug.Print "Standard not initialised"
        IUnknown_QueryInterface = E_POINTER
              
    'ERROR here  
    ElseIf InvokeQueryInterface(this, riid, ppvObject, defaultQIfunction) = S_OK Then
        Debug.Print "Interface found on default, returning that"
        IUnknown_QueryInterface = S_OK
        
    ElseIf compositionInterface Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "CompositionInterface not set"
        IUnknown_QueryInterface = E_NOINTERFACE
        
    Else
        Debug.Print "Checking Composition Class"
        IUnknown_QueryInterface = InvokeQueryInterface(ObjPtr(compositionInterface), riid, ppvObject)
        If IUnknown_QueryInterface = S_OK Then Debug.Print "Interface found on composition class"
        
    End If
    
End Function

Sub t()
    Dim c As DoNothingClass
    Set c = New DoNothingClass
    Set compositionInterface = New Collection
    defaultQIfunction = DefaultVTableFuncPtr(c)
    DefaultVTableFuncPtr(c) = VBA.CLngPtr(AddressOf IUnknown_QueryInterface)
    
    Debug.Print "Typename(c):="; TypeName(c)
    Dim castTo As Collection
    Set castTo = c
    Debug.Print "Typename(c):="; TypeName(c)
    Debug.Print "Typename(castTo):="; TypeName(castTo)
    
End Sub
```

Is giving me a compile error. I don't understand because `InvokeQueryInterface` function is right there! So I assume I've made a blunder somewhere else in the module, anyone see it?

This is a screenshot of the error:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found it:

```
ByVal this As IUnknown -> ByVal this As LongPtr
```

VBA can be so cryptic sometimes...

Comment: So, does that goes inside of `ElseIf InvokeQueryInterface(this, riid, ppvObject, defaultQIfunction) = S_OK` replacing what is currently there? Why is this the right fix?

Comment: @QHarr Just because the `InvokeQueryInterface` function expects a longptr and I was trying to supply it with an IUnknown. Both declarations are compatible with `IUnknown_QueryInterface` which is why I got it wrong.